# Wordpress Subdomain sites redirect to main site

Tags: wordpress, redirect, https, ssl-certificate, multisite

We use wordpress and our subdomain sites recently started redirecting to our main site.

Exmaple, sub.example.com/products redirects to https://example.com/products and gets a 404.

I did notice if I add https:// in front of the subdomain it goes to the proper subdomain site. What would cause that? How would I fix that issue? I want the user to be able to put sub.example.com and get the proper site without needing to type in the https part.

The only thing that I remember changing recently was adding the ssl certificate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced this issue. Check for any wordpress plugins forcing HTTPs on any http domains. Or anything on your subdomain forcing https when it isn't an https site.

Comment: All our subdomains are https sites. Would your suggestion still matter? Sites pull up properly with https in front. It just redirects to main site when it is like sub.example.com